# mplot3d (python) why plotting a line in 3d the coordinates need the metod flatten

Tags: python, matplotlib, flatten, mplot3d

I'm starting to learn python and the related graphical library.
After some experience in 2D I started to use 3D.
What I would like to do is plotting a circle in 3D.
I report a minimal example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))  # only solution to define axis aspect equal
ax = fig.add_subplot((111), projection='3d')

t = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, 360, endpoint=True)

x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)
z = zeros((1, len(x)))

ax.plot(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten(), color='red')

plt.show()
```

The question is: why if I use only `x`, `y`, `z` (without `flatten`) I obtain an error like:

> input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis remapping?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the shape of `z`. You've defined it as `(1,N)`, when it should be `(N,)`.
Use `z = np.zeros(shape=t.shape)` and you won't need to flatten your array anymore

Comment: Yes. You, Diziet Asahi, are right. Thank you for your clarification.